# CRM Dynamics Workflow Designer like Nintex Workflow?

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, workflow-foundation-4, crm, sharepoint-designer

I have fairly complex workflows to be developed. I, naturally, could've gone for SharePoint + Nintex Workflow, but as a technology constraint I must use CRM workflows.

I was hoping that I could find something like Nintex Workflow for CRM Dynamics that gets integrated into its designer; exactly like Nintex does with SharePoint. So that I can design **complex workflows** within CRM itself, rather than using SharePoint -- Idea is to use CRM as xRM itself.

In this case, I could rely on following:

- Simple workflows --> use CRM designer
- Complex --> use Nintex Workflow + windows workflow foundation

**Question: Can CRM2011 be used to develop complex workflows? Using WWF, or any other third party workflow engine?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the question friend?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom XAML workflows and registered them in Dynamics CRM 2011 using Visual Studio (or theoretically other commercial products), but this is only support for the On-premise installation.

See this link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309458.aspx